# How to show options in the user profile only if the user is an admin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to load some extra author options to the profile pages of a Wordpress site, however, even though these options apply to every user, they should only be able to be modified by an admin user, therefore, is there a way to hide the options if the user is not an admin? but show them when editing other profiles as an admin user?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be performed but not out of the box.

[Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

It is available using certain plugins

[Lime PLugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/lime/)